# How to strip html tag for elements that haw no ID and Class

Tags: php, dom, domxpath

Long story short! I need to remove all SPAN tags that has no ID and Class set. I found DOMXPath query selector that works, but i can't wrap my head around how to remove tag and leave text untouched.

Note about first `foreach`: first `foreach` is looping sentences, so I need to get all processed value back in `$splited_sentences` array.

```
foreach ($splited_sentences as $sentence_key => $sentence_value) {
  $html_dom = Html::load($sentence_value);
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($html_dom);

    foreach ($xpath->query('//span[not(@id) and not(@class)]') as $element_key => $element) {
      // Not working Idea, all commented code is just idea to represent needed outcome:
      // $just_text = stip_html($element);
      // $splited_sentences[$sentence_key] = str_replace($element, $just_text);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use strip_tags() to remove any html tags try to following code :

```
foreach ($splited_sentences as $sentence_key => $sentence_value) {
  $html_dom = Html::load($sentence_value);
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($html_dom);

    foreach ($xpath->query('//span[not(@id) and not(@class)]') as $element_key => $element) {
        $just_text = strip_tags ($element);
        $splited_sentences[$sentence_key] = str_replace($element, $just_text);
    }
}
```